# When to use all lowercase

Tags: website-design, advertisement, letter-case

On the internet, and in certain shops, I've noticed that sometimes each word is capitalised in, for instance an advert or navigation bar and logo; sometimes sentence case is used and sometimes all lower case is used. I just wondered if there's some kind of rule as to when each is used or something... Does it relate to the target audience, colours, desired effect or something?`

Answer (score 1):

- CAUTION: ALL CAPS SHOULD ONLY BE USED IN WARNING TEXT
- Title Case is For Titles, and Other Important Headings
- Sentence case is for narrative text, and you should always include a period after it.
- lower case only appropriate for bullet text
- dOn'T eVeN cOnSiDeR uSiNg MiXeD cAsE, eVeR

These are just general guidelines, though - consult a real internet style guide, like the [Web Style Guide, 3rd edition](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/), or Yahoo's [The Web Content Style Guide](http://styleguide.yahoo.com) if you are actually going to be creating content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the links, they should be very useful. However, maybe this isn't the most appropriate place to ask about 'non-virtual' content but sometimes posters and TV adverts and things use all lower case, or all uppercase - is this to do with the harshness of the message or how friendly the advertising campaign is meant to be or something?

Comment: @Andy  Posters and TV adverts do not focus on UX and readability as much as on graphics and their own motives. There are no rule in that jungle. https://www.google.com/search?gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=UmES5UfzKp2DXXAHFPdOxQ&suggest=p&pq=james+bond+movie+poster&cp=8&gs_id=12&xhr=t&q=movie+posters&newwindow=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.dmg&biw=1595&bih=846&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=VMDEUb-IO_bd4APir4Ag see if you can find a pattern here.

Comment: @rk Ah thank you. From what I can see on Google Images most movie posters actually use all capitals, or at least Title Case. It seems to be that uppercase gives a more dramatic effect and is used with darker backgrounds where as lowercase is used for things like comedies and animated films because it is more subtle. Would this stand to reason? Or is there really no starting point whatsoever - do the designers/artists really just experiment until they think adverts look good?